# JS function call with brackets

Tags: javascript, syntax, socket.io

I've been debugging some issue I'm having on socket.io and stumbled accross this (`lib/transport.js` line 345):

```
  var current = this.manager.transports[this.id];
```

however

```
typeof this.manager.transports = [Function]
```

and the declaration is as follows (`lib/manager.js` line 928):

```
Manager.prototype.transports = function (data) {
    //some stuff, returns an array
}
```

Can someone explain what's going on here? Are there missing some parenthesis `transports()[this.id]`?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Here's the code for the function

```
Manager.prototype.transports = function (data) {
  var transp = this.get('transports')
   , ret = [];

   for (var i = 0, l = transp.length; i < l; i++) {
     var transport = transp[i];

     if (transport) {
       if (!transport.checkClient || transport.checkClient(data)) {
         ret.push(transport);
       }
     }
   }

 return ret;
};
```

Comment: Without seeing more code, it's indeterminate.  Even if it is a function, there's nothing necessarily wrong with accessing properties from the object (because remember, functions are objects). Look closely at the **end** of the assignment, where your comment says "returns an array".

Comment: @Pointy updated my answer to show the code of the function

Comment: So that's code in socket.io somewhere?  Where is the code from? I can't find a "transport.js" in the current github repository (well the one I found at least).

Comment: It's in the 0.9.14 branch @Pointy

Comment: @Pointy were you able to find it? here's the link https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/0.9.14/lib/transport.js

Comment: Yes, I found it. I'm not sure exactly what that code is doing, but there are many places that reference that "transports" property like an object to look up properties by id.

Comment: Maybe what's happening is that the Manager instances are *supposed* to have "transports" be an array, but for some reason your instance is not being properly initialized.

Comment: @Pointy yeah... it's kinda confusing. Already opened a new issue on the socket.io git page..

Answer (score 0):

javascript functions are basically javascript objects, so when this line:

```
this.manager.transports[this.id]
```

is executed its basically saying get the property in the `transports` function/object that has the key `this.id`

you can test this in console by doing the following:

```
function myFunction() {
   alert("inside function");
}
myFunction[3] = "Hi";
console.log( typeof(myFunction) );
console.log( myFunction[3] );
myFunction();
```

Comment: Yes, I get that functions can be objects, but also when doing `console.log(this.manager.transports);` the only thing I get is the function itself, not any other properties that could be added, also, after adding some `console.log` to the function in question, It gets executed when it is "called" with the brackets so I'm kinda lost